# re-explain or reinterpret?

Tags: american-english

I'm having a little confusion when typing these words to my customer. So we talk about things that I don't understand what they are saying/ what are their instructions? So, I kindly ask them to explain it again. The issue I'm having here is should I use re-explain or reinterpret?

Please help me with this issue. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use neither.

"To interpret" is something that's done by the *receiver* of the message, not by the sender. In this case, *you* need help interpreting your customer's requirements.

While "re-explain" can mean "explain in a different manner", it is very likely to not be taken (or interpreted) like this, so there is a chance that your customer will just send the same message again.

The better choices, as pointed out in the comments, would be *rephrase* or *clarify*. Furthermore, you should be more specific about *what exactly* in your customer's instructions you don't understand, otherwise they'll also be stumped trying to figure out which part of their message is not clear.

A few examples:

**Customer:** I need a big table for a family dinner tomorrow

**You:** Could you *clarify* what you mean by "big"? Do you have any measurements or at least number of seats in mind?

---

**Customer:** I'm not satisfied with your product, what are the possibilities for a refund?

**You:** We would like to better understand what happened, would you be so kind as to *rephrase* your complaint? Which aspects of the product were not delivered to your satisfaction?

Comment: @Lambie edited, thank you!

Comment: 'Interpret' has various meanings. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/interpret) has: << **interpret** [verb] [transitive] 1.  to explain the meaning of; make understandable.  (...) >> This contradicts '"To interpret" is something that's done by the receiver of the message, not by the sender.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth However, the first meaning they list is the same one I mention, "If you interpret something in a particular way, you decide that this is its meaning or significance". Pragmatically, it is better to not use "interpret" anyhow to minimize the chance of misunderstanding

Comment: But ' "To interpret" is something that's done by the receiver of the message, not by the sender.' is wrong. // ' "To interpret" usually [though not always] refers to something that's done by the receiver of the message, not by the sender. So pragmatically, it is better to not use "interpret"  to minimize the chance of misunderstanding.' is, on the other hand, quite acceptable.